JWTEncoder: Failed to select a JWK signing key
I have an auth-server + resource server in one app. I've spent a lot of time searching and debugging, but there aren't many updated pages or topics about Spring Boot 3.+ related to this. So, I had this working and wanted to add a custom secret that will be shared between my client and server. And here is where the problems started...
This is my auth+resource server config:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Value("${security.jwt.secret}")
private String jwtSecret;

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                           CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"), new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));

    http.cors(customizer -> customizer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource));
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                    authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/oauth2/authorize").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
            .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin.loginPage("/login").permitAll())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()));
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()));
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(jwtSecret);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
    OctetSequenceKey octetKey = new OctetSequenceKey.Builder(secretKeySpec)
            .keyID("customKey")
            .build();
    JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(octetKey);
    JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource = (jwkSelector, context) -> {
        List<JWK> keys = jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
        if (keys.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("No keys found matching selection criteria!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Keys selected: " + keys.stream().map(JWK::getKeyID).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
        }
        return keys;
    };

    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(jwkSource);
}

@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(jwtSecret);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(secretKeySpec).build();
}
}

And i have in my app.properties:
security.jwt.secret=r26BoWWyTQMp/8rkD3RnRKsbHkRsmQWjTvJTfmhrQxU=

I had everything working with asymmetric way (private and public key), but I wanted to try this wat too...
Now, when logging in with the client, I always receive:
org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtEncodingException: An error occurred while attempting to encode the Jwt: Failed to select a JWK signing key

What am i missing in the server?


I have fixed the issue with this:
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

@Value("${jwt.key}")
private String jwtKey;

private final TokenService tokenService;

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http,
                                                           CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource) throws Exception {
    OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
    http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

    http.exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"), new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((resourceServer) -> resourceServer.jwt(jwtSpec -> {
                jwtSpec.decoder(jwtDecoder());
            }));

    http.cors(customizer -> customizer.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource));
    return http.build();

}

@Bean
SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authz -> authz
                    .requestMatchers("/hello").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .jwt(jwt -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder().build();
}

@Bean
WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/h2-console/**"));
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
    return tokenService.jwtCustomizer();
}

@Bean
public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
    return tokenService.jwtEncoder();
}

@Bean
public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(jwtKey);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA256");
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withSecretKey(keySpec).build();
}
}

And the TokenService class:
@Service
public class TokenService {

@Value("${jwt.key}")
private String jwtKey;

public OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
    return context -> {
        if (OAuth2TokenType.ACCESS_TOKEN.equals(context.getTokenType())) {
            context.getJwsHeader().algorithm(MacAlgorithm.HS256);
            Date expirationDate = 
Date.from(Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofHours(5)));
            Date issueDate = Date.from(Instant.now());
            context.getClaims().claims(claims -> {
                claims.put("exp", expirationDate);
                claims.put("iat", issueDate);
                claims.put("custom", "custom");
            });
        }
    };
}

public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
    return parameters -> {
        byte[] secretKeyBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(jwtKey);
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKeyBytes, "HmacSHA256");

        try {
            MACSigner signer = new MACSigner(secretKeySpec);

            JWTClaimsSet.Builder claimsSetBuilder = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder();
            parameters.getClaims().getClaims().forEach((key, value) ->
                    claimsSetBuilder.claim(key, value instanceof Instant ? Date.from((Instant) value) : value)
            );
            JWTClaimsSet claimsSet = claimsSetBuilder.build();

            JWSHeader header = new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.HS256);

            SignedJWT signedJWT = new SignedJWT(header, claimsSet);
            signedJWT.sign(signer);

            return Jwt.withTokenValue(signedJWT.serialize())
                    .header("alg", header.getAlgorithm().getName())
                    .subject(claimsSet.getSubject())
                    .issuer(claimsSet.getIssuer())
                    .claims(claims -> claims.putAll(claimsSet.getClaims()))
                    .issuedAt(claimsSet.getIssueTime().toInstant())
                    .expiresAt(claimsSet.getExpirationTime().toInstant())
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Error while signing the JWT", e);
        }
    };
}
}


A couple of things i would try:
I would make myself sure that the JWKSelector used by the NimbusJwtEncoder matches exactly the criteria you expect, Otherwise the selector could be looking for specific attributes (like use or alg) that you did not define.
I would also add an exception or logging error to help with the debugging process
for JWKSource
Lastly you could try simplify the configuration before testing to see if there is anything abnormal, something like this:
/* rest of code */
@Bean
public JwtEncoder jwtEncoder() {
    String jwtSecret = "your-secret-key"; // non-Base64 encoded secret for testing
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(jwtSecret.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
    return new NimbusJwtEncoder(secretKeySpec);
}
/* rest of code */

If this configuration works without errors, the issue is probably in the custom JWK selection logic, publish your findings after this and we go from there
